# Bootstrap 4.3 - Using a card image overlay to create a sale tag

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm finishing up an e-commerce site.  I display items as Bootstrap cards on the index page, and would like to create a little "Sale!" tag in the upper corner of the cards for every item that is on sale.  I've played around with various sizing and position utilities, but I haven't been able to get it right.  What I currently have:

Markup, with some Symfony template code:

```
<div class="card-deck">
{% for newestProduct in newestProducts[1:] %}
    <div class="card d-flex">
        <img class="card-img-top w-100" src="{{ asset('product_images/' ~ newestProduct.filename) }}">
        {% if newestProduct.hasSale == true %}
            <div class="card-img-overlay bg-success text-white w-25 px-2 m-2" style="height: 1rem;">Sale!</div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ newestProduct.name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">${{ newestProduct.price }}/{% if newestProduct.isFabric == true %}yd{% else %}ea{% endif %}</p>
            <a class="btn btn-burnt-orange" href="{{ path('_store_product_details', {'slug': newestProduct.slug, 'prodId': newestProduct.id}) }}">Check it out!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Which results in:

[image]

The biggest problem with this is that the height of the block is too high... I'm not entirely sure how to address it.  The Bootstrap utilities start at 25%.  It seems like an issue stemming from using `card-img-overlay`.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is there an easier, more elegant, or simply *better* way to do what I want?

Comment: what is your desire output would you please explain little more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position-relative` on the `<div class="card d-flex">` and `position-absolute` on the img to position the sale tag instead of the `card-img-overlay` on the image.  Also you need to set top and left as 0 to make it work correctly in  IE.

```
<div class="card-deck">
{% for newestProduct in newestProducts[1:] %}
    <div class="card d-flex position-relative">
      <img class="card-img-top w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200"> 
      {% if newestProduct.hasSale == true %}
          <div class="position-absolute bg-success text-white  px-2 m-2">Sale!</div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ newestProduct.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${{ newestProduct.price }}/{% if newestProduct.isFabric == true %}yd{% else %}ea{% endif %}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-burnt-orange" href="{{ path('_store_product_details', {'slug': newestProduct.slug, 'prodId': newestProduct.id}) }}">Check it out!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Styles Added:

```
.sale-div {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
.sale-div {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card d-flex position-relative">
      <img class="card-img-top w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200"> {% if newestProduct.hasSale == true %}
      <div class="sale-div position-absolute badge badge-success  p-2 m-2">Sale!</div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ newestProduct.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${{ newestProduct.price }}/{% if newestProduct.isFabric == true %}yd{% else %}ea{% endif %}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-burnt-orange" href="{{ path('_store_product_details', {'slug': newestProduct.slug, 'prodId': newestProduct.id}) }}">Check it out!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card d-flex position-relative">
      <img class="card-img-top w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200"> {% if newestProduct.hasSale == true %}
      <div class="sale-div position-absolute badge badge-success  p-2 m-2">Sale!</div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ newestProduct.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${{ newestProduct.price }}/{% if newestProduct.isFabric == true %}yd{% else %}ea{% endif %}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-burnt-orange" href="{{ path('_store_product_details', {'slug': newestProduct.slug, 'prodId': newestProduct.id}) }}">Check it out!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card d-flex position-relative">
      <img class="card-img-top w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200"> {% if newestProduct.hasSale == true %}
      <div class="sale-div position-absolute badge badge-success p-2 m-2">Sale!</div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ newestProduct.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${{ newestProduct.price }}/{% if newestProduct.isFabric == true %}yd{% else %}ea{% endif %}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-burnt-orange" href="{{ path('_store_product_details', {'slug': newestProduct.slug, 'prodId': newestProduct.id}) }}">Check it out!</a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

P.S.: You can use `badge badge-success` instead of `bg-success text-white` to get a more better sale tag if you feel.